# Radare's `aaaa` and -AA what does it do, exactly?

Tags: radare2, static-analysis

When I run `aaa`, Radare tells me,

```
[x] Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis.
```

But what does `aaaa` do? It's not documented under `aa?` nor `aaa?` nor

```
[0x000028e0]> aaa?
Usage: See aa? for more help
[0x000028e0]> aaaa?
Usage: See aa? for more help
```

And `man radare` isn't more useful only saying,

```
 -A  run 'aaa' command before prompt or patch to analyze all referenced code. Use -AA to run aaaa
```

`radare --help`, says

```
 -A run 'aaa' command to analyze all referenced code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute the `aaa` command, radare is showing you what are the steps it takes. Each step has the command responsible for it inside parentheses.

```
[0x00000000]> aaa
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[x] Analyze function calls (aac)
[x] Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
[x] Constructing a function name for fcn.* and sym.func.* functions (aan)
[x] Type matching analysis for all functions (afta)
[x] Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis.
```

As you can see, `aaa` is a command which is executing other commands. It also prints a short description of what each command is doing. A little bit more detailed information can be found under `aa?`. So, to append this information together:

- aa - alias for `af@@ sym.*;af@entry0;afva`
- aac - analyze function calls (`` af @@ `pi len~call[1]` ``)
- aar - analyze len bytes of instructions for references
- aan - autoname functions that either start with `fcn.*` or `sym.func.*`
- afta - do type matching analysis for all functions

Similar to `aaa`, this information is being printed when `aaaa` is executed.

```
[0x00000000]> aaaa
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[x] Analyze function calls (aac)
[x] Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
[x] Constructing a function name for fcn.* and sym.func.* functions (aan)
[x] Enable constraint types analysis for variables
```

The main change of `aaaa` is "[x] Enable constraint types analysis for variables". This basically enables the `anal.types.constraint` configuration variable.

```
[0x00000000]> e? anal.types.constraint
anal.types.constraint: Enable constraint types analysis for variables
```

---

On a personal note here, I would suggest not to use `aaaa` since it is quite buggy sometimes and probably would not be necessary.